# Visual Studio 2013 Team Explorer/Git integration missing files

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2013

I've set up Visual Studio 2013 with the native Git integration & BitBucket.

This has worked fine so far, but I noticed that Visual Studio stopped tracking newly created files (created through the IDE, such as simple new .cs files) for upload to BitBucket.

- Commit/Push for changes from already tracked files still works fine
- The new files **are not** showing up in the Excluded Changes or Untracked Files lists
- The new files **are** included in the project files (and those are showing the correct changes)
- The files are definitely **not** excluded any other way (.gitignore or otherwise).

What else may cause the new files to not get tracked anymore?

Comment: Just in case anyone comes across this - as a workaround I was able to exclude the files from the projects and then re-include them which caused Visual Studio to finally pick them up as new files. Not ideal, files are easily missed, but that's all I could do.

Comment: Alex, could you clarify what you mean by exclude and re-include?

Comment: Lemme break it down for you @EdwardThomson: Solution Explorer -> Right Click -> Exclude From Project; then Solution Explorer -> Show All Files -> "select excluded file" -> Right Click -> Include In Project.

I had this problem yesterday. I'm not quite sure how and why it happened. I guess it was while I did a file "clone". Very annoying to do this. Eery feeling to see that files are being excluded from source control at random. Bad, bad, bad.

Comment: This issue is still lingering about. Is there a ticket for this at microsoft connect? I want to upvote it, but I'm unable to find one.

Comment: I am facing the same issue in one of the development machine in our team while its not there in other machines, any fix?

Comment: Similar problem here.VS2k13, latest updated. Sporadic. Sometimes files are not tracked.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I experienced something similar recently but excluding and then re-including the missing files didn't work for me. In VS2013 Premium, I noticed there's a "Untracked Files" section at the bottom of the Changes window. It was simply a matter of right-clicking the files I wanted to include and adding them. Not ideal, indeed, but another work-around.

Comment: I did the same with hawkke. Pretty stupid but at least it works.

Comment: Can you explain the problem further?  New files should be untracked, by design.

Comment: @EdwardThomson Basically new files show up as untracked when using GIT, but when using TFVC new files are automatically tracked as part of the pending changes. I don't think it's a bug, but it isn't as convenient as it is when using TFVC. It isn't a big deal once you know you have to manually track new files/folders, but it can be a bit confusing for people new to GIT (like me).

Comment: I've been committing all this time, only now to realise that not everything is getting pushed. Glad it never got to a stage where I had to rely on those commits. Only just found out when I swapped a new computer in and made a pull request.

Comment: VS2015 update 2 has just got rid of the untracked files section. Any ideas how to solve this now? Or get back the untracked files view?

Comment: ok nvm, it shows they are untracked by having "[add]" next to the file, instead of having their own section

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem as OP:

- Commit/Push for changes from already tracked files still works fine
- The new files are not showing up in the Excluded Changes or Untracked Files lists
- The new files are included in the project files (and those are showing the correct changes)
- The files are definitely not excluded any other way (.gitignore or otherwise).

So, it appears that visual studio somehow thinks these files are tracked, while they're not, as they do not show up under untracked files.

**My workaround**

As I cannot add the untracked files in visual studio, the workaround is to use git bash, and manually do git add  for each file that should be added. After that they work fine within visual studio again.

I hope this is fixed soon... apart from this bug, the git integration seems very nice from the short time I've tried it.

Comment: I also noticed that VS seems to work again after using git bash. It will be interesting to see for how long.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem where I added a .cs file, and VS doesn't recognize it as added, and won't included it in my changes.

As a workaround, you can open up [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (mad by Atlassian to work with BitBucket), look at the "Unstaged Files" section, and right click > Add the file. VS will immediately pick up the change/add and you can commit via VS.

Not ideal, as you still can't trust/rely on VS to track your commits.

Answer (score 2):

even if it's quite old question, I've got a similar problem last week on VS2013 and none of previews workarounds are efficents for me.
While editing a file, it's appear on Team Explorer list of modify files but, as soon as they are saved, they disaperead from any lists. Other tools (git bash, tortoise, ...) saw them as modify and uncommit but not VS.
I solutionne this problem in the parameter of Git in Team Explorer by generating the .gitIgnore file of the solution ! I hope this could help.

It could be related to:
[Git changes not showing in VS2013 Update 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770855/git-changes-not-showing-in-vs2013-update-2)

Comment: I had this problem on a new machine with a fresh install of both VS2013 Update 5 and VS 2015 and it was driving me crazy. Then I found if I installed Git for Windows, the problem went away!  https://git-for-windows.github.io/

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing in Visual Studio 2013 version 12.0.21005.1 REL, where I would put a test file, hello.cs, in a particular folder and it would show up as "Untracked", and yet if I put the same file in a different folder, also in the same overall repository folder, it wouldn't show up anywhere (included, excluded, or untracked).

It turns out that I had some deep folders with Bootstrap and JQuery that, themselves, had .gitignore and .gitattribute files, and when I simply renamed them to disabled.gitignore and disabled.gitattribute, and then hit the little refresh icon at the top of the Visual Studio Team Explorer pane, all my missing files sprang up again! Yeah!

It seems like it's a bug in Visual Studio 2013, and perhaps older versions, because I would have expected the .gitignore files to only have scope within their own folders, but they seem to carry on effect as Visual Studio continues traversing the entire folder hierarchy, and not particularly in alphabetical or depth-first/depth-last sequence!

Comment: If you think there's a bug in our gitignore handling, please file a detailed bug with the contents of your gitignore(s).  Certainly, it is by-design that gitignores apply to subdirectories, too, depending on the contents.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and my solution is using of the TortoiseGit. If I want to commit, in section "Not versioned files" TortoiseGit shows me files not matched in .gitignore but added to file system . You can simply check all (if you'd like to add them) and press commit.

[image]

This is not only one issue with Visual Studio Git. Especially general error messages with no value. Every time I had to switch to the TortoiseGit or to the Git bash to find what Visual Studio Git tool doesn't like.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have this issue as well, turned out to be my installed git in windows beeing old. Update it and VS will be able to track and commit git repos once again

https://msysgit.github.io/

Comment: Thanks, this is what gave me the idea above to install Git for Windows and it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved this problem by adding it manually from shell.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding a `.gitignore` file in my local repository at the same level as my `.git` folder.

1. In Team Explorer while connected to your Git project, click the drop-down and select `Settings`
2. Under `Git` click `Git Settings`
   [image]
3. Toward the bottom, under `Repository Settings > Ignore File` click `Add`
   [image]

This will create a default .gitignore file for you.  This worked for me, but you can also replace then content of the file with the something like what is recommended here: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/VisualStudio.gitignore

Hope this helps somebody!

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but encountered a new cause to this problem.
I got it after including a downloaded plugin. The plugin had it's own .git folder in it, which seemed to interfere with VS's git.
After removing the folder, I renamed every non-tracked file then named it back to the original, and VS started adding the + in front of the files indicating they are now tracked...

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. Removing from the project and adding it back didn't work, even when doing commits between each step. I ended having to use Source Tree to write the commit, and the use VS to push it to vsto.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same issue and non of the mentioned solutions helped. I wasn't able to commit a file in any way to Bitbucket Git repo from VS2015. What I've ended up with is I've made a change to the file (didn't save it), staged the file and then commit it. Source Tree also was able to track it as 'Added'.